# typescript how to type the subset of a string literal array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have function, **createFields**, taking a generic Object type, in this case, User, with a set of keys. I want the type the subset of these keys, to be inferred with a string literal array, like **selectable** property in  Fields. Can I do it in typescript? If yes, how can i achieve it? Thank you.

```
Here is the code
interface User {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Fields<T extends object = {}> {
  selectable: Array<keyof T>;
  sortable: Array<keyof T>;
}

function createFields<T extends object = {}>({ selectable, sortable }: Fields<T>) {
  return {
    // How can I get type of selectable to be ("id" | "username" | "age")[]
    select(fields: typeof selectable): string {
      return fields.join(',')
    }
  }
}
const UserFields: Fields<User> = {
  selectable: ['id', 'username', 'age'],
  sortable: ['username', 'age']
}

const fields = createFields(UserFields)
// actual
// => fields.select = (fields: ("id" | "username" | "password" | "age")[]): string;

// expected 
// => => fields.select = (fields: ("id" | "username" | "age")[]): string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Fields<T>` isn't sufficiently generic.  Its `selectable` and `sortable` properties are `Array<keyof T>`, which is too wide to remember *which* subset of `keyof T` is used.  The way I'd deal with this is to make `createFields()` accept a generic type `F` that is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Fields<T>`.

One issue you face doing this is that the compiler can't do [partial type argument inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  You either need to specify both `T` and `F`, or let the compiler infer both.  And there really isn't anything for the compiler to infer for `T`.  Assuming you want to specify `T` the way I'd do this is to use currying:

```
const createFieldsFor =
    <T extends object>() => // restrict to particular object type if we want
        <F extends Fields<T>>({ selectable, sortable }: F) => ({
            select(fields: readonly F["selectable"][number][]): string {
                return fields.join(',')
            }
        })
```

If you don't care about the particular `T`, then you can just leave it unspecified entirely:

```
const createFields = <F extends Fields<any>>({ selectable, sortable }: F) => ({
    select(fields: readonly F["selectable"][number][]): string {
        return fields.join(',')
    }
})
```

Notice that the argument to `fields` is `readonly F["selectable"][number][]`, meaning: look up the `"selectable"` property of `F`, and look up its `number` index type (`F["selectable"][number]`)... and we are accepting any array or readonly array of that type.  The reason I don't just use `F["selectable"]` is because if that type is a tuple of fixed order and length, we don't want `fields` to require the same order/length.

---

For either the curried or non-curried case you need to make `UserFields` an object type that doesn't widen to `Fields<T>` and doesn't widen `selectable` and `sortable` to `string[]`.  Here's one way to do it:

```
const UserFields = {
    selectable: ['id', 'username', 'age'],
    sortable: ['username', 'age']
} as const; // const assertion doesn't forget about sting literals
```

I used a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to keep `UserFields` narrow.  This as the side effect of making the arrays `readonly` which `Fields<T>` doesn't accept, so we can change `Fields<T>` to allow both regular and read-only arrays:

```
interface Fields<T extends object> {
    // readonly arrays are more general than arrays, not more specific
    selectable: ReadonlyArray<keyof T>;
    sortable: ReadonlyArray<keyof T>;
}
```

Or you can make `UserFields` some other way instead.  The point is you can't annotate it as `Fields<User>` or it will forget everything you care about.

---

The curried solution is used like this:

```
const createUserFields = createFieldsFor<User>(); 

const fields = createUserFields(UserFields); // okay

const badFields =
    createUserFields({ selectable: ["password"], sortable: ["id", "oops"] }); // error!
    // "oops" is not assignable to keyof User ------------------> ~~~~~~
```

Notice how there's an error in `badFields` because `createUserFields()` will complain about non-`keyof User` properties.

Let's make sure the `fields` that comes out works as expected:

```
fields.select(["age", "username"]); // okay
fields.select(["age", "password", "username"]); // error!
// -----------------> ~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '"password"' is not assignable to type '"id" | "username" | "age"'
```

That's what you wanted, right?

---

The non-curried don't-care-about-`User` solution is similar, but it won't catch `"oops"`:

```
const alsoFields = createFields(UserFields);
const alsoBadFields =
    createFields({ selectable: ["password"], sortable: ["id", "oops"] }); // no error
```

---

I guess which one (if any) you want to use depends on your use case. The main point here is that you need `createFields()` to be generic in the type of the keys in the `selectable` and `sortable` properties.  Exactly how you do that is up to you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4ChkHLAAmAXMiAK4C2ARtANz6GWZQhzUTnphSgBzJoWQAHOOnQB3APZQyyXvxBDmBOAO4Ua9KEwC+uXKEixEKAGLAIAG2LoAPABVkEAB6QQ95DNoArCAQwAD4cNWQAegjkKAg4YhkQGwBPZDgoKDhk9DTY5Go5FE0QaDgbZDAACzgQXMzsgBoKGTB8wsVRQOAYYARwzBtAsDhaQfIAJTiEpOSAQQyshwBrCGSZGGQnYOFCdDlh0a1J+MSU+frl1fXN7dxDXARE3mQEWLhIK1t7CzlkAF5ws5XB4IF4cr4AkFggAKACU-1CURiECUvVaYBkYnSYF6lBs6R8-iGFWSnSIGykKCkNTA4REDgswM83k+dkcWxh2EUtiGI0GTT2UAOg2Q+nIFnhf1C0LwIjlux5QWhPS+6HIb2mKWQFgA2gAiAa8w56gC6OqodGgZpNsJ4fEEYXlTsIsTAlHYyBVbIAdH4ZKBoQByBqB2F0p2GZ36MMPJ6tV5xD7WNn-ZAMpmglnJ+wOGrJYKc7mDIJ8iAC-al0XiyXS2UK4tgZXZtXIk4zbX6w0l41mi26a22xT2lSOp2u921L32X3+kBBkNhkSGaNGWMgZ4YaCs7x-UcELvCrQ6wMkYPIQOsaAcLhnwMaCCBk0NfoVw7kY+X9icB9NO+aR93GkOSPOuYAMJE0Qgc8EhsDiiTIAkKIgIGrQwHImitCMMiUK0vAOjYwCmGU6BGFB8ZvJAm5QNuOS7gm7wQDRPxQA4VEwrCTBrs8tDxDR-zhPRlFsDRMpFkaYzIPq4iSLI8imuWQqlu+eokHqTR6jIMiiOgpqihxEGuBkcgAIS4EiIgaVpOlEDkIAtEB6DAAIHCHBUmIrGsGxUcgAC0fn+QFgX+aEAB+YXhVxqHNqmgkQFRInxc2HGkXGaQ2HsfF0RRjHNtCiWqslZFpXsABCvHRQCIixSJXIHkpkl6tJ0hyMQ8mKK+En6qp6madpunRuBSJ2YZUByEYU7oN6B7Qvq95qcgeqfteECmvpSIyEsWS4BNU2Ko2s2aPNjUwbJrXqUt36rYN0TQKNUCmUiQVPQFoXhW9YVmdETikiggbHTJLV6oGNnNJhkhOS5IoYiSZJ-apyAAD4LRdXB6ojC1zYGuBAA)

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly and it is what I want. But it adds more complexity with the wrapper function createFieldsFor. I wonder whether this piece of code is having a bad design, or just typescript does not support it at this moment.